# Async function doesn't return, despite promise resolve() being called

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Trying to iterate through lines in a file using 'line-reader' in an async function that uses the "new Promise<..." approach.  In a debugger, I can confirm that the resolve function is called, but the async function never returns.  Kind of baffled by it.

Async function:

```
import * as lineReader from 'line-reader';
import * as fs from 'fs';

export async function iterateMyFileAsync(filename: string): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
      if (!fs.existsSync(filename)) {
        reject(new Error("file " + filename + " doesn't exist"));
        return;
      }

      lineReader.eachLine(filename, (line, last) => {

        // would want to do things, but issue repros without anything here

        if (last) {
          resolve()
        }
      });
    });
}
```

Elsewhere:

```
await iterateMyFileAsync('myfile.txt');
```

In a debugger I can confirm that resolve() is definitely being called, but iterateMyFileAsync() never returns.  Why might this happen?

Comment: What's your evidence that `iterateMyFileAsync()` never returns.  I find that hard to believe unless you have some sort of infinite loop you aren't showing us.  FYI, `async` functions return BEFORE their promise is resolved (if you have any asynchronous operations).  That's why they return a promise in the first place.

Comment: Also, use of `fs.existsSync()` in an `async` function really makes no sense.  Use async I/O.

Comment: The code you show does not do what you say - it returns a promise just fine before the first line has been read.  So, either you're confused about what your code is doing or there's more code to this issue than you're showing us and thus you aren't disclosing what is needed to understand the situation.

Comment: Here you are using eachline array utility function which do not allow await operation inside it.Remember that await only affects the innermost async function that surrounds it and can only be used directly inside async functions. That is a problem if you want to use one of the Array utility functions map(), forEach(), etc., which rely on callbacks.

Comment: Please check the your dev console. The issue is with the `line-reader` package. It does not work on my side and  there is an error on the console: https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-36chq. It is cool to keep an eye on the console with javascript development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I solved this shortly after the question was posted, sorry for not closing this.  It had to do with the debug workflow not working right, a breakpoint wasn't being hit when it should have been, leading me to think something impossible was happening.

Answer (score 0):

**Update after some digging and peers review comments**

Your haved marked the function as `async` which will automatically convert your function to a promise. It is not nescessary to return a promise again.

The package `line-reader` seams not to work for some reason I can't explain. From npm it has been last published 3 years ago. [check this codesanbox for failing exemples](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-36chq) with `line-reader` `eachLine` and `onpen` APIs.

**Try n-readlines npm package**. I managed to make it work and it befits your usecase. Or, you can try node [built in package readLine](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_readline).

```
import lineByLine from 'n-readlines';
import * as fs from 'fs';

export async function iterateMyFileAsync(filename: string): Promise<void> {
  if (!fs.existsSync(filename)) {
    throw new Error('file ' + filename + " doesn't exist");
  }

  const liner = new lineByLine(filename);
  let line;

  while ((line = liner.next())) {
    console.log('Line ', line.toString('ascii'));
  }

  return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I don't think this is correct, though. Removing the async keyword as in the second example has no effect. The first example returns before the file has finished iterating, which isn't the desired behavior.

Comment: he's correct this will end up as Promise<Promise<void>> to get around this chuck "await" infront of "new Promise" in the original code

Comment: @cclauson, your need to add return after if(last) on the first example. I updated the code. The lineReader take a callback as 3rd param, you might want to use it first before looking at Promise. Do add a codepen or codesandbox link, it will be easier to assist.

Comment: This is incorrect - `Promise<Promise<?>>` simply is not possible in JS (anything with a `then` method is subsumed into the current promise - `return somePromise` is always `flatMap`-ed, if you like)

Comment: This isn't the issue.  It's OK (not required, but OK) to return a promise from an async function.  It just uses that promise as the return value rather than create a new one.  There's no wrapping of a promise inside a promise.

Comment: @jfriend00 how about the fact that there is typescrit transpiler kicking in? Could it not affect the final expected result?.

Comment: You can rule that out by looking at the transpiled code directly, but I doubt it.  What is your transpiling target?  Are you transpiling to ES7 (that has `async/await`)?

Comment: @jfriend00, indeed your are very right, it works. The issue is with the `line-reader` package. It does not work and  there is an obvious error on the console.

Answer (score 0):

If your file is `empty`, your promise will `not resolve`.

Here is the spec of `line-reader` when the input file is empty:

- [should not call callback on empty file](https://github.com/nickewing/line-reader/blob/5ee8df854b0d23ee4055d4e1f1b9d8dabc74769d/test/line_reader.js#L220)

```
        it("should not call callback on empty file", function(done) {
          lineReader.eachLine(emptyFilePath, function(line) {
            assert.ok(false, "Empty file should not cause any callbacks");
          }, function(err) {
            assert.ok(!err);
            done()
          });
        });
```

You should modify your code like this to handle `empty file` case:

```
    import * as lineReader from 'line-reader';
    import * as fs from 'fs';

    export async function iterateMyFileAsync(filename: string): Promise<void> {
      return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
        if (!fs.existsSync(filename)) {
          reject(new Error("file " + filename + " doesn't exist"));
          return;
        }

        lineReader.eachLine(filename, (line, last) => {
          // would want to do things, but issue repros without anything here
        },
          (err) => {
            if (err) {
              reject(err)
              return;
            }

            resolve()
          });
      });
    }
```